# How to draw axis and line graph using paintComponent in JPanel

Tags: java, graph, jpanel, paintcomponent

i need to create a line graph inside a JPanel using paintComponent. I don't want to use external package.

I have to draw different line graph ( in the same panel ) and user selects the number of graph to draw. The data for every graph are number from 1 to a max ( i can calculate it ). My problem is to create axis and to show good the varius graph with different color. Can someone help me? can someone show me something? thanks you very much!

Comment: Have you searched SO as there are plenty of examples here including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java/8693635#8693635)?

Comment: i've seen it, but it is only for one line graph so he create axis in function of number of element in list. but if i have some lists with different number inside it how can i do?

Comment: By altering the code to fit your need. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that [jfreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) is the better solution..