# Graph on VB.NET/Java

Tags: java, vb.net

How can I create a line graph in Java OR VB.NET with the following data?

```
Sales Rep       # of Sales      Date
Anthony         15              August 1
Anthony         17              August 2
Mark            27              August 1
David           27              August 1
Mark            30              August 2
David           14              August 2
```

Comment: The below link could be helpful http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Graphics/linegraphonly.htm

Comment: And this as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.Net, put your data into a `DataTable` and bind it to a [`Chart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456391) control

Tutorials on how to bind a `DataTable` to a `Chart` are [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/net/Binding-a-Microsoft-Chart-with-a-Dataset.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexgor/archive/2009/02/21/data-binding-ms-chart-control.aspx).

Also, there a some open-source chart controls like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10966/Cristi-Potlog-s-Chart-Control-for-NET) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET).

**Edit:**

Here's a simple example to show you how the `Chart` works:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    table.Columns.Add("Sales Rep", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("# of Sales", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(Date))

    table.Rows.Add("Anthony", 15, "2012 August 1")
    table.Rows.Add("Mark", 27, "2012 August 1")
    table.Rows.Add("David", 27, "2012 August 1")

    table.Rows.Add("Anthony", 17, "2012 August 2")
    table.Rows.Add("Mark", 30, "2012  August 2")
    table.Rows.Add("David", 14, "2012 August 2")

    Chart1.Series.RemoveAt(0)
    Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(table.DefaultView, "Sales Rep", "Date", "# of Sales", "")

    For Each s In Chart1.Series
        s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]

---

Using Java, have a look into [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/), which can also render different kinds of charts (and there a probably a lot of other Java controls/libs for displaying charts).

[image]

Comment: Sure. I'll add an example later

Comment: Got it working in vb.net. And the data was actually linked to a database (forgot to add that to my question). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There's an open source function at [www.ezVB.net](http://www.ezvb.net/draw-graph-from-1d-or-2d-array/).

The advantages are that

1) It takes only one line to implement, e.g.

```
ezDrawGraph({{0.5, 1, 3.14}, {1.2, 3, 4}}).Save("testgraph.png", Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

2) The function can be copied directly into your code. No libraries needed.

3) It accepts either one 1D array, a set of two 1D arrays or one 2D array.

The drawdown is that the design is very basic.

*(P.S. I am affiliated with ezVB.net)*