# Draw a X,Y line Chart with Java

Tags: java, charts

I have this structure:

```
HashMap<Double, Integer>>  times
```

Where the Kay is a time (dobule) and the value is the number of occurence of this time.
For example i have:
time: 1.65 occurence: 10;

I need to plot a line chart with the time on X axis and the occurence on Y axis.

What i can use of very simple?

Comment: possible duplicate of [drawing a simple line graph in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

[JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) will handle this easily with a time series chart.  You can either copy your data into the default time series dataset implementation ([TimeSeries](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeries.html) and [TimeSeriesCollection](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html) classes), or you can wrap your own data structure within a class that implements the [XYDataset](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html) interface (that way you don't need to duplicate your data).