# Applet shows up blank, not initializing?

Tags: java, methods, applet, jtextfield, bluej

Hello everyone my name is Fyree! I have an assignment for an introductory Java course where I need to create a program that takes user input for the beginning values, and all five year values to make a line graph (but that is for another post), and also print the rate. Here is my problem, when I try to run this applet it opens (it compiles without error), but only shows up as a blank screen, and says applet not initialized at the bottom of the applet. I am not sure why this is (currently I am trying to get the rate part of the assignment working where it takes the year five value and beginning value given by the user, and uses them to print out the rate of growth or interest). I want to know why this is happening, and what I need to do to correctly have the rate output on the screen (or under the line graph once I have that put in). Any help would be appreciated as this assignment is due tomorrow!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class Rate_Graph extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
JLabel bv, ev1, ev2, ev3, ev4, ev5;
JTextField bv1, ev_1, ev_2, ev_3, ev_4, ev_5;
JButton go, add1, add2, add3, add4, add5;
public void init()
{
    setLayout(new FlowLayout()); //This sets the preferred layout format

    bv = new JLabel("Enter beginning value:"); //Beginning value input
    bv1 = new JTextField(5);

    ev1 = new JLabel("Enter year 1 value:"); //Year 1 value input
    ev_1 = new JTextField(5);

    ev2 = new JLabel("Enter year 2 value:"); //Year 2 value input
    ev_2 = new JTextField(5);

    ev3 = new JLabel("Enter year 3 value:"); //Year 3 value input
    ev_3 = new JTextField(5);

    ev4 = new JLabel("Enter year 4 value:"); //Year 4 value input
    ev_4 = new JTextField(5);

    ev5 = new JLabel("Enter year 5 value:"); //Year 5 value input
    ev_5 = new JTextField(5);

    go = new JButton("Add!"); //Button that implements all the values
    go.addActionListener(this); //So it does something
    add(bv); add(bv1); //Adding all of the different things
    add(ev1); add(ev_1);
    add(ev2); add(ev_2);
    add(ev3); add(ev_3);
    add(ev4); add(ev_4);
    add(ev5); add(ev_5);
    add(go);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
        /*Object src = event.getSource(); 
        if(src==go){
            String strbv = bv1.getText();
            String strev1 = ev_1.getText();
            String strev2 = ev_2.getText();
            String strev3 = ev_3.getText();
            String strev4 = ev_4.getText();
            String strev5 = ev_5.getText();
        }*/
}
int intbv = Integer.parseInt(bv1.getText());
int intev1 = Integer.parseInt(ev_1.getText());
int intev2 = Integer.parseInt(ev_2.getText());
int intev3 = Integer.parseInt(ev_3.getText());
int intev4 = Integer.parseInt(ev_4.getText());
int intev5 = Integer.parseInt(ev_5.getText());
public double computeRate()
{
    double rate = (Math.pow(intev5 / intbv, 1.0 / 5.0) - 1);
    return rate;
}
}
```

Comment: You tagged bluej. Are you using bluej, or are you using java? Have you ever had an applet come up and show you a UI, or is the your first attempt? And why an applet at all?

Comment: I am using an applet because the professor requires me too. Also BlueJ is just an IDE to help make coding with Java easier. Do you have any idea why this is going on though? Also I am not sure why it is downvoted, since it is a valid question, and the tags are correct.

Comment: No, bluej is not really java. People ask strange questions all the time here because they are using some strange bluej feature and none of us Java programmers can understand what they are talking abourt.

Comment: I just added that as a tag because I could not think of another one. BlueJ is not a different programming language. Anyway are you able to help me out?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are getting `NullPointerException` because you are trying to initialize `intbv`, `intbv1`, ... by using `JLabel`'s `bv`, `bv1`, .... which are not yet initialized.

Just only declare `intbv`, `intbv1`, `intbv2`...(not initialize), and assign them values when any action is performed in `actionPerformed`.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    intbv = Integer.parseInt(bv1.getText());
    intev1 = Integer.parseInt(ev_1.getText());
    intev2 = Integer.parseInt(ev_2.getText());
    intev3 = Integer.parseInt(ev_3.getText());
    intev4 = Integer.parseInt(ev_4.getText());
    intev5 = Integer.parseInt(ev_5.getText());
    int sum = intbv + intev1 + intev2 + intev3 + intev4 + intev5;
    System.out.println("Sum            : " + sum);
    System.out.println("Compute rate   : " + computeRate());
}
int intbv;
int intev1;
int intev2;
int intev3;
int intev4;
int intev5;
```

[image]

Comment: I changed that, but the "Add!" button still does not do anything, and also it is supposed to be able to print out the rate with the computeRate() method that I am using above.

Comment: Why will it do anything. You have not coded for that. If you want to get sum of all values then just add `intbv`, `intbv1`.... and print it.

Comment: I need to use this method to figure out the rate: public double computeRate()
    {
        double rate = (Math.pow(intev5 / intbv, 1.0 / 5.0) - 1);
        System.out.println(rate);
        return rate;
    } (also it has to be its own method, I have made the mistake before of not doing that and I lost points off the assignment). It is not just the sum, I have to use a formula to find the rate of the growth that takes in, and uses the user input values to figure out, and print what the rate would need to be.

Comment: I have edited my code, please look it first. I have used `computeRate()` too. or may be there is something else you are trying to say.

Comment: It is still not doing anything (I am not even using the "Add!" button, I took that out for now). It is not printing the rate.

Comment: I don't know why it is not working for you. But it is working for me and I know it is correct. [here is the complete code in pastebin.com to help you more.](http://pastebin.com/Ky7eCqXe) and that's it.