# Creating a line graph with user input

Tags: java, methods, graph, line, bluej

So I am having a problem with even starting to create a line graph that takes in the values given by the user. I have the code that I have so far (currently only computes the rate of growth which is part of the assignment). So what I need to do is to take all the values that the user inputs (bv1, ev_1, ev_2, ev_3, ev_4, and ev_5...), and use them to plot points on a line graph that has the amount of money on the Y-Axis, and the year on the X-Axis. For the labels of the graph I am also supposed to use HTML formatting in Java for the labels for the axes. I know I am supposed to use stuff like superpaint g, and @Override, but I am not sure where to start (some example code would help). Any help is appreciated as this assignment is due tomorrow!

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class Rate_Graph1 extends JApplet implements ActionListener
{
double E, B, N;
JLabel rateTitle, firstBv, ev1, ev2, ev3, ev4, ev5, returnRate;
JTextField bv1, ev_1, ev_2, ev_3, ev_4, ev_5, usersRate;
JButton calc;
public void setTop()
{
    rateTitle = new JLabel("Calculate your return rate!", JLabel.CENTER);
    add(rateTitle, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
public void setMiddle()
{
    firstBv = new JLabel("Enter the beginning value:");
    bv1 = new JTextField("", 15);

    ev1 = new JLabel("Enter the value after the first year:");
    ev_1 = new JTextField("", 15);

    ev2 = new JLabel("Enter the value after the second year:");
    ev_2 = new JTextField("", 15);

    ev3 = new JLabel("Enter the value after the third year:");
    ev_3 = new JTextField("", 15);

    ev4 = new JLabel("Enter the value after the fourth year:");
    ev_4 = new JTextField("", 15);

    ev5 = new JLabel("Enter the value after the fifth, and final year:");
    ev_5 = new JTextField("", 15);

    JPanel pane1 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    pane1.add(firstBv);
    pane1.add(bv1);

    pane1.add(ev1);
    pane1.add(ev_1);

    pane1.add(ev2);
    pane1.add(ev_2);

    pane1.add(ev3);
    pane1.add(ev_3);

    pane1.add(ev4);
    pane1.add(ev_4);

    pane1.add(ev5);
    pane1.add(ev_5);

    JPanel mainPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1));
    mainPane.add(pane1);
    add(mainPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public void setBottom()
{
    returnRate = new JLabel("Your return rate is:");
    usersRate = new JTextField("", 15);
    calc = new JButton("Calculate Rate!");
    calc.addActionListener(this);
    JPanel pane4 = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    pane4.add(returnRate);
    pane4.add(usersRate);
    pane4.add(calc);

    add(pane4, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
public void init()
{
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setTop();
    setMiddle();
    setBottom();
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getSource() == calc){
        E = Double.parseDouble(ev_5.getText());
        B = Double.parseDouble(bv1.getText());
        double rate = Math.pow(E / B, 1.0 / 5.0) - 1;
        usersRate.setText(+ rate * 100 + "%");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First decide where you are going to draw the graph. You need some component on your layout. Is it a panel? Where is that panel?

Comment: I want to do it something like this, but with HTML labels: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java. I am not sure where to start in my case though.