# Java Swing - Repaint() don't work correctly

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, mousemotionlistener

I take program from [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java). I try to edit points in real-time mode. I add MouseMotionListener to the constructor and write some basic functions to get near point to mouse and edit this point. When I get (x,y) points in the constructor, `repaint()` works strange. When I get (x,y) points in `paintComponent`, `repaint()` doesn't work at all. So, this are images with getting (x,y) in the constructor and in `paintComponent`. Where is my mistake?

```
package simplegrapher2;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import static java.lang.Math.sqrt;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleGrapher2 extends JPanel {

    private int width = 800;
    private int heigth = 400;
    private int padding = 25;
    private int labelPadding = 25;
    private Color lineColor = new Color(44, 102, 230, 180);
    private Color pointColor = new Color(100, 100, 100, 180);
    private Color gridColor = new Color(200, 200, 200, 200);
    private static final Stroke GRAPH_STROKE = new BasicStroke(2f);
    private int pointWidth = 4;
    private int numberYDivisions = 10;
    private List<Double> scores;
    private static double serieX = 0;
    public List<Point2D.Double> graphPoints;

    public SimpleGrapher2(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
                double x = me.getX();
                double y = me.getY();
                findNearPoint(x, y);
                editSerie(x, y);
                revalidate();
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {}
        });

        double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
        double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

        graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            double x1 = (double) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
            double y1 = (double) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
            graphPoints.add(new Point2D.Double(x1, y1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        /*double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
        double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

        graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            double x1 = (double) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
            double y1 = (double) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
            graphPoints.add(new Point2D.Double(x1, y1));
        }*/

        // draw white background
        g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding, getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);
        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        // create hatch marks and grid lines for y axis.
        for (int i = 0; i < numberYDivisions + 1; i++) {
            int x0 = padding + labelPadding;
            int x1 = pointWidth + padding + labelPadding;
            int y0 = getHeight() - ((i * (getHeight() - padding * 2 - labelPadding)) / numberYDivisions + padding + labelPadding);
            int y1 = y0;
            if (scores.size() > 0) {
                g2.setColor(gridColor);
                g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding + 1 + pointWidth, y0, getWidth() - padding, y1);
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                String yLabel = ((int) ((getMinScore() + (getMaxScore() - getMinScore()) * ((i * 1.0) / numberYDivisions)) * 100)) / 100.0 + "";
                FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(yLabel);
                g2.drawString(yLabel, x0 - labelWidth - 5, y0 + (metrics.getHeight() / 2) - 3);
            }
            g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        }

        // and for x axis
        for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
            if (scores.size() > 1) {
                int x0 = i * (getWidth() - padding * 2 - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1) + padding + labelPadding;
                int x1 = x0;
                int y0 = getHeight() - padding - labelPadding;
                int y1 = y0 - pointWidth;
                if ((i % ((int) ((scores.size() / 20.0)) + 1)) == 0) {
                    g2.setColor(gridColor);
                    g2.drawLine(x0, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding - 1 - pointWidth, x1, padding);
                    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    String xLabel = i + "";
                    FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
                    int labelWidth = metrics.stringWidth(xLabel);
                    g2.drawString(xLabel, x0 - labelWidth / 2, y0 + metrics.getHeight() + 3);
                }
                g2.drawLine(x0, y0, x1, y1);
            }
        }

        // create x and y axes 
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
        g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);

        Stroke oldStroke = g2.getStroke();
        g2.setColor(lineColor);
        g2.setStroke(GRAPH_STROKE);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size() - 1; i++) {
            double x1 = graphPoints.get(i).x;
            double y1 = graphPoints.get(i).y;
            double x2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).x;
            double y2 = graphPoints.get(i + 1).y;
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        }

        g2.setStroke(oldStroke);
        g2.setColor(pointColor);
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
            double x = graphPoints.get(i).x - pointWidth / 2;
            double y = graphPoints.get(i).y - pointWidth / 2;
            int ovalW = pointWidth;
            int ovalH = pointWidth;
            //g2.fillOval(x, y, ovalW, ovalH);
        }
    }

    public void findNearPoint(double x, double y) {
        double delta = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < graphPoints.size(); j++) {
            double sx = graphPoints.get(j).x;
            double sy = graphPoints.get(j).y;
            double root = sqrt((x-sx)*(x-sx) + (y-sy)*(y-sy));
            if (j == 0) {
                delta = root;
                serieX = sx;
            }
            else if (root < delta) {
                serieX = sx;
                delta = root;
            }
        }
    }

    public void editSerie(double x, double y) {
        double tmpSerieX = serieX;
        int ind = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < graphPoints.size(); i++) {
            if (graphPoints.get(i).x == tmpSerieX) {
                ind = i;
            }
        }
        graphPoints.remove(ind);
        graphPoints.add(ind, new Point2D.Double(x, y));
        serieX = x;
    }

    private double getMinScore() {
        double minScore = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            minScore = Math.min(minScore, score);
        }
        return minScore;
    }

    private double getMaxScore() {
        double maxScore = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        for (Double score : scores) {
            maxScore = Math.max(maxScore, score);
        }
        return maxScore;
    }

    public void setScores(List<Double> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
        invalidate();
        this.repaint();
    }

    public List<Double> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        List<Double> scores = new ArrayList<>();
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxDataPoints = 40;
        int maxScore = 10;
        for (int i = 0; i < maxDataPoints; i++) {
            scores.add((double) random.nextDouble() * maxScore);
        }
        SimpleGrapher2 mainPanel = new SimpleGrapher2(scores);
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry, i don't understand what do u mean. In the constructor `repaint()` works but graphic is in the corner and I don't know how to make this right

Comment: Sorry focused on the wrong part, thought you meant when you dragged...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your constructor when you calculate the `x/yScale`...

```
public SimpleGrapher2(List<Double> scores) {
    //...
    double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
    double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());
    //...
}
```

At the point the component is constructed, the components size is `0x0`.  You need to wait until the component is resized in some meaningful way before calculating the points...

This is also problematic, as the component may be resized a number of times, in quick succession, when it is first realised onto the screen.

What I've done in the past is used a Swing `Timer` set to a smallish delay to allow the component to be resized a number of times over a small time scale.  Once it's all settled down, the `Timer` will trigger and you can perform you required operations, for example...

```
public SimpleGrapher2(List<Double> scores) {
    //...
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        private Timer initTimer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                initTimer.stop();
                double xScale = ((double) getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding) / (scores.size() - 1);
                double yScale = ((double) getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding) / (getMaxScore() - getMinScore());

                graphPoints = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++) {
                    double x1 = (double) (i * xScale + padding + labelPadding);
                    double y1 = (double) ((getMaxScore() - scores.get(i)) * yScale + padding);
                    graphPoints.add(new Point2D.Double(x1, y1));
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            if (graphPoints == null) {
                initTimer.restart();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

All this does is waits until the timer between the `compoentResized` event is more then 200 milliseconds (you can play with this value to get it closer to what you want, but I've found roughly 250 milliseconds to be a reasonable delay)

You will need to correct the `paintComponent` to allow for `graphPoints` been `null` as well.

Comment: if ( initTimer.isRunning ) then initTimer.restart(); else initTimer.start(); becase componentResized is called from every pixel (ensure that is set initTimer.setRepeat (false) )

Comment: No, I want the timer reset each time componentResized is called, I want the events to consolidate into a single event after a defined delay, that's the point. Yes I'd normally use setRepeats, but because the way I've initialised the listener, I can't call it, so, instead, I just stop it when actionPerformed is called

Comment: and initTimer.start(); can be/is started from/by..., be sure it should be fragile..., (as always) your decision :-)

Comment: (about delay at 200milis) good mediaplayers (installed, standard PC) shows me half second (plus minus citybus) in cellphone is delay quite longer

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to play with it, but the idea is I'm waiting for a minimum time between possible events. The value would need to be played with