# Use arraylist to plot data using graphics2d

Tags: java, arraylist, plot, graphics2d

I am very new to data visualization. Currently, I already have my data in .csv format which is stored in an arraylist. Now i need to plot the data in a parallel coordinate graph. Technically i have to insert all the data into the first 2 axis.

[image: Something like this.]

I only know how to plot single data only. Can anyone please give me a sample on how to plot the data using arraylist. I am sorry I couldnt post any code till now, because i dont know where to start actually. I even saw [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8693342/drawing-a-simple-line-graph-in-java) from stackoverflow. Please i need someone to help me on this.

Comment: May be start with [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Comment: You might consider having a look at JFreeChart

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have already created the axis but now i want to group the whole .csv data into the axis. Can you help on that. I have considered JFreeChart too but i dont want to use any plugins.